# select2 + clone + ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, clone

i am trying to clone row of select2 which will later call the same ajax function. Am not able to get the combination of select2 + clone + ajax working correctly. Will appreciate any help

The code below ajax post script on its own is working but cloning the tr row and is not working

[image]

```
 <tr><td>Select Sectors</td>
 <td><div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="pull-left" id="sectordiv">
<table width="650px" id="sector" class="sector margin-bottom">
<tbody>
<tr class="tr_clone">
<td style="width: 250px;"><select class="form-control select2  xxx countryselect" name="countryid[]" id="countryid" style="width: 250px;">
<?
$Querycountries = "SELECT * FROM  countries  order by name asc";
$resultcountries = $link->query($Querycountries);
?>
<option value="<? print $rowcountries['id']; ?>"><? print $rowcountries['name']; ?></option><? } ?>
</select>
</td>
<td style="width: 250px;" valign="middle"><select class="form-control select2 xxx" name="cityid[]" id="cityid" style="width: 250px;"><option value="idno">city name</option>
</select>
</td>
<td style="width: 100px;"><input name="no_of_nights[]" type="number" class="form-control" id="no_of_nights[]" placeholder="No of nights" style="50px;" min="1"></td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div> &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus-circle addmore btn btn-primary pull-left "></i>
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle removebtn btn btn-danger pull-left"></i>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.countryselect').on('change', function() {
      var country_id = this.value;
      $.ajax({
         url: "getCity.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {
            country_id: country_id
         },
         cache: false,
         success: function(result){
            $("#cityid").html(result);
         }
      });
   });    
   
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.addmore', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $lastTr = $tr.closest('.sector').find('tr:last');

    $lastTr.find('.xxx').select2('destroy');

    var $clone = $lastTr.clone();

    $clone.find('td').each(function() {
        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
        if (id) {
            var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
            el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
            el.attr('name', prefix + (+i + 1));
        }
    });
    $tr.closest('tbody').append($clone);

});
</script>
```

Comment: what doesn't work please elaborate .

Comment: As mentioned above the ajax post for single row is working. Cloning is not working, if cloned successfully second row ajax post should work as well. Any idea?

Comment: you need to bind your event handler with some static elements because your selects are dynamically created so change `$('.countryselect').on('change', function() {` this to `$(document).on('change','.countryselect',function(){`